# Upgraded to 12.04 and now the WiFi applet doesn't show wireless connections to connect to

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager

I upgraded Ubuntu to 12.04 and everything is fine expect I now have no option to connect to WiFi.

Under the WiFi applet in the upper top right where I would typically open the applet and see WiFi signals that the computer finds and that I can connect to, when I open the applet there are no Wifi signals listed to choose from.

It shows from top to bottom in *white* text: VPN Connections, Enable Networking and Edit Connections; it shows in *dark* text that I can't open: Wired Network, disconnected and Connection Information.

Any ideas what to do? Basically the computer software doesn't show the option of connecting to the WiFi now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that your Wireless Card isn't being detected, or needs restricted drivers to work properly.

Try to connect thru ethernet to the internet, open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it updates your system.

Then, go to **System Definitions > Hardware** and open **Aditional Drivers**

It should open a window with the restricted and opensource drivers for your wireless board.
You just have to select and activate the one that you want.